# EF Core Enumeration class throwing exception

Tags: ef-core-2.1

I am using an enumeration class like this:

```
public class BillTransactionState
{
    public static readonly BillTransactionState Initialized = new BillTransactionState(1, "Initialized");
    public static readonly BillTransactionState Invoiceable = new BillTransactionState(2, "Invoiceable");
    public static readonly BillTransactionState NoSow = new BillTransactionState(3, "NoSow");
    public static readonly BillTransactionState Invoiced = new BillTransactionState(4, "Invoiced");

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have another class that references BillTransactionState:

```
public class BillTransactionStateHistory : IEntity<long>
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public BillTransactionState BillTransactionState { get; set; }
}
```

In my webapi, when I do something like this:

```
var billTransactionStateHistory = new BillTransactionStateHistory ({
        BillTransaction = BillTransaction .Initialized,
        EffectiveDate = DateTime.Now
      });
_dbContext.BillTransactionStateHistories.AddAsync(billTransactionStateHistory)
```

I get an error:

> Identity insert is off for BillTransactionState.

I realized EF Core is trying to insert a row in BillTransactionState table with values 1 (for Id) and 'Initliazed'. How can I stop EF Core from trying to insert a row in this enumerated class. Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Identity insert is off for table BillTransactionState. But why is it even trying to insert into BillTransactionState?

Comment: "How can I stop EF Core from trying to insert a row in this enumerated class."-this line is not clear to me! Would you please explain further what you actually wanting?

Comment: Sure. When I try to add BillTransactionStateHistory, why is EF Core trying to add a row in BillTransactionState?

Comment: This is because you have added `BillTransactionState` as navigation property in `BillTransactionStateHistory` entity. Why have you added  `BillTransactionState` this in `BillTransactionStateHistory`? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: A billTransactionStateHistory will always have a BillTransactionState and EffectiveDate. In the datamodel, BillTransactionStateHIstory have a foreign key BillTransactionStateId which references primary key of BillTransactionState.

Comment: Your `BillTransactionState` class is not understandable to me! Does it represent any database table? May be not. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Write your `BillTransactionStateHistory` model class as follows:

```
public class BillTransactionStateHistory : IEntity<long>
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public int BillTransactionState { get; set; }
}
```

**Note: After that don't forget to update the database accordingly!**

Then in the Web API Method:

```
var billTransactionStateHistory = new BillTransactionStateHistory ()
{
   BillTransactionState = BillTransactionState.Initialized.Id,
   EffectiveDate = DateTime.Now
};
_dbContext.BillTransactionStateHistories.AddAsync(billTransactionStateHistory)
```

Comment: This will work but I really want to associate BillTransactionState to BillTRansactionStateHIstory rather than just the Id. Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes! Possible. Then you have to make some changes in database level.

Comment: What are the changes? Can you provider some insight.

Comment: It will take time to write here! Rather it would have been better if I had the opportunity directly write on your project via some tool.

Comment: That option is not available due to security reasons.

Comment: Sorry! Then I cannot do anything more! I have tried my level best to help you. Better study a lot and hope you will find the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12150#issuecomment-394008709) answer on the official EF Core GitHub repository.

Your enumeration class and entity class would remain the same. You would have to introduce a `ValueConverter` or use `PropertyBuilder.HasConverter` to provide your mappings to and from `BillTransactionState` and `int`.

Lambda example:

```
// builder is IEntityTypeConfiguration<BillTransactionStateHistory>
builder.Property(e => e.BillTransactionState)
  .HasColumnName("state")
  .HasConversion(state => state.Id, stateId => SomeLookupMethod(stateId));

public BillTransactionState SomeLookupMethod(int id)
{
  // TODO: Lookup transaction state based on id.
}
```

**Please be aware** that EF Core 2.x has issues with value converters and lambdas properly mapping to query expressions. EF Core 3.x has fixed this ([related issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12045))